# Hierarchy Query - Aggregate the nodes

Tags: oracle, hierarchy, common-table-expression

Need an assistance in hierarchy query , I have 2 tables , one holds hierarchy  structure between the elements and second one holds active alarm per element .

```
create table hrc (parent_id number, child_id number);
insert into hrc (parent_id,child_id) values (null,1);
insert into hrc (parent_id,child_id) values (1,2);
insert into hrc (parent_id,child_id) values (2,0);
insert into hrc (parent_id,child_id) values (0,76292);
insert into hrc (parent_id,child_id) values (0,96689);
insert into hrc (parent_id,child_id) values (0,12429);
insert into hrc (parent_id,child_id) values (0,10697);
insert into hrc (parent_id,child_id) values (0,60856);
insert into hrc (parent_id,child_id) values (0,99460);
insert into hrc (parent_id,child_id) values (76292,57120);
insert into hrc (parent_id,child_id) values (12429,25152);


commit
/
create table alarms (id number,element_id number) ;

insert into alarms (id,element_id) values (1,0);
insert into alarms (id,element_id) values (2,0);
insert into alarms (id,element_id) values (3,0);
insert into alarms (id,element_id) values (4,76292);
insert into alarms (id,element_id) values (5,76292);
insert into alarms (id,element_id) values (6,57120);
insert into alarms (id,element_id) values (7,57120);
insert into alarms (id,element_id) values (8,57120);
insert into alarms (id,element_id) values (9,25152);
insert into alarms (id,element_id) values (10,25152);
insert into alarms (id,element_id) values (11,12429);
commit;
```

The next query represent the hierarchy

```
with q (parent_id,child_id, hierlevel,root) as
( 
select parent_id,child_id, 0,child_id root 
from   hrc 
where  parent_id  = 0
UNION ALL  
select  hrc.parent_id,hrc.child_id ,q.hierlevel + 1 , q.root 
       from   hrc
         join
         q
         on (q.child_id=hrc.parent_id)

)select * from q
```

I want to join ( left outer ) to alarms tables and get the count of the alrams per element but just for the first level for example , for choosing parent_id=0 
The required output is :

COUNT                    ROOT

---

```
                   5      76292
                   3      12429
                   0      60856
                   0      10697
                   0      99460
                   0      96689
```

Element 76292(5)  - 3 of his alarms of his own  and his child (57120) has 2 .
  for  12429 (3) -  1 of his own and 2 of his child . 
The rest has 0 alarms .

The preferred way is using CTE and not connect by .

Thanks for the help .

Answer (score 2):

You can't do the join/aggregate inside the recursive CTE - you'd get ORA-32486: unsupported operation error.

You can keep your CTE as it is and just join that to the alarms table, and group by the root ID:

```
with a as (...)
select q.root, count(a.id)
from q
left join alarms a on a.element_id = q.child_id
group by q.root
order by count(a.id) desc; -- or whatever

      ROOT                             COUNT(A.ID)
---------- ---------------------------------------
     76292                                       5
     12429                                       3
     99460                                       0
     10697                                       0
     96689                                       0
     60856                                       0
```